# Bayesian networks and joint probabilities

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

**This is my problem**

My problem is modeled by a basic Bayesian Network with only two layers. So I have parent and child nodes but the children has no children. Essentially a bipartite graph. The children depend on one or more of the parents and these edges/relations have a probability. The model is also extended by completing the bipartite graph with low probability edges to account for noisy data. So in the finished model each child $(C_x)$ has a dependency on each parent $(P_x)$.

What I want to be able to do is to infer the most probable solution by maximizing,

$$ max_{P_1,P_2,\dots,P_n}(P(P_1,P_2,\dots,P_n|C_1,C_2,\dots,C_m)) $$ 
where $ C_i \in \{0,1\} $, $ P_j \in \{0,1\} $. For a given observation on the state of the children.

So for a observation $O=\{C_1=0, C_2=1, C_3=1\}$

I want to calculate
$$P(P_1=1,P_2=0,P_3=0|C_1=0, C_2=1, C_3=1)$$
$$P(P_1=0,P_2=1,P_3=0|C_1=0, C_2=1, C_3=1)$$
$$P(P_1=1,P_2=1,P_3=0|C_1=0, C_2=1, C_3=1)$$
and so on.

**Here is how I try to solve it**

I want to be thorough so I will explain how I try to solve this. I'm not sure that I'm doing it right. Please point out to med if I'm doing this wrong.

What I do first is I complete the conditional distribution tables for the child nodes. From the model I have the CPT as for a child node $C_x$ something like this, the probabilites are chosen to make the example easy.

\begin{array}{ l l l|l l }
P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P & \lnot P \\
  \hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0.1 & 0.9 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0.4 & 0.6 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0.8 \\
\end{array}

And I complete this table by calculating

\begin{array}{ l l l|l l }
P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P & \lnot P \\
  \hline
 0 & 1 & 1 & (1- \lnot P) & 0.9 \times 0.6 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & (1- \lnot P) & 0.9 \times 0.8 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & (1- \lnot P) & 0.6 \times 0.8 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & (1- \lnot P) & 0.9 \times 0.6 \times 0.8 \\
\end{array}

And then I calculate the joint conditional probability by doing something like

$$P(P_1=1,P_2=0,P_3=0|C_1=0, C_2=1, C_3=1) = $$
$$P(P_1=1,P_2=0,P_3=0|C_1=0) \times$$ 
$$P(P_1=1,P_2=0,P_3=0|C_2=1) \times$$
$$P(P_1=1,P_2=0,P_3=0|C_3=1)$$

Basically I'm not convinced that the last step is correct. **Any help or comments is greately appreciated!**

Yes, this is school related but it is not regular homework. It is a part of a thesis project I'm doing at a company.

**Graph update on request**

[image: Graph]

Here is a graph example of my model. The regular edges are direct dependencies and the dotted edges are noisy or guess edges added to allow for noisy data. Guess edges has a low probability of $p = 0.0001$ and the regular edges all have the probability $(1-p)$. In my problem I do not care for the probability of individual events like $P(L_1)$ or $P(C_2)$, so they are assumed to be $1$. I make an observation on the state of the variables $C_1...C_n$ and given the graph model above I want to infer to most plausible cause. The possible causes  are $P_1...P_n$ or a combination of them that is most likely. Like I stated earlier on the example observation above.

Here is an example of the basic truth tables for this graph.
\begin{array}{ l|l l }
C_1 & T & F \\
  \hline
 P_1 & 0.9999 & 0.0001 \\
 P_2 & 0.9999 & 0.0001 \\
 P_3 & 0.9999 & 0.0001 \\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{ l|l l }
C_2 & T & F \\
  \hline
 P_1 & 0.0001 & 0.9999 \\
 P_2 & 0.9999 & 0.0001 \\
 P_3 & 0.9999 & 0.0001 \\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{ l|l l }
C_3 & T & F \\
  \hline
 P_1 & 0.0001 & 0.9999 \\
 P_2 & 0.0001 & 0.9999 \\
 P_3 & 0.9999 & 0.0001 \\
\end{array}

Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: Anyone, please? Can I make something more clear?

Comment: That would be a lot more helpful to understand the problem if you provide a graph with nodes and directed edges as well as CPTs denoted besides the nodes.

Comment: @Rasoul, I added a graph and tables, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your CPT's are not correct. You must have $2^3=8$ rows for all possible combinations of $P_i=\{\text{True}, \text{False}\}$, $i=1,2,3$ which are parent nodes of each $C_i$, $i=1,2,3$. For example,

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & Pr(C_1=\text{T}|P_1,P_2,P_3) \\
\hline
\text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} & 0.4 \\
\text{T} & \text{T} & \text{F} & 0.5 \\
\text{T} & \text{F} & \text{T} & 0.3 \\
\text{T} & \text{F} & \text{F} & 0.7 \\
\text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} & 0.1 \\
\text{F} & \text{T} & \text{F} & 0.9 \\
\text{F} & \text{F} & \text{T} & 0.2 \\
\text{F} & \text{F} & \text{F} & 0.6 \\
\end{array}
$$
As I understand the problem from your BN graph, you are looking for the maximum probable state of $P_i$'s given $C_i$'s,

$$\text{max } Pr(P_1,P_2,P_3|C_1,C_2,C_3)$$

Your Bayesian Network joint probability can be written as,

$$Pr_{BN} = Pr(P_1,P_2,P_3,C_1,C_2,C_3)=\prod_{i=1}^3 Pr(C_i|P_1,P_2,P_3) \tag{  1}$$

and

$$Pr_{BN} = Pr(P_1,P_2,P_3|C_1,C_2,C_3)Pr(C_1,C_2,C_3)$$

You can find $Pr(C_1,C_2,C_3)$ by marginalizing $Pr(P_1,P_2,P_3,C_1,C_2,C_3)$.

$$Pr(C_1,C_2,C_3)=\sum_{P_1=\{\text{T},\text{F}\}}\sum_{P_2=\{\text{T},\text{F}\}}\sum_{P_3=\{\text{T},\text{F}\}}Pr(P_1,P_2,P_3,C_1,C_2,C_3)\tag{2}$$

So here are the steps:

1) Redesign CPT's correctly

2) Compute $Pr_{BN}$ using formual (1)

3) Compute $Pr(C_1,C_2,C_3)$ by marginalizing $Pr_{BN}$ using formula (2)

4) Compute $Pr(P_1,P_2,P_3|C_1,C_2,C_3) = \dfrac{Pr_{BN}}{Pr(C_1,C_2,C_3)}$

5) Compute the maximum of $Pr(P_1,P_2,P_3|C_1,C_2,C_3)$ and observe which set of $\{P_1, P_2, P_3\}$ maximizes the probability. That set is the answer.

**Edit 1:** The way you are estimating CPT's is not correct. I assume that the events $P_i$'s are independent and that they are conditionally independent given the event $C_i$, hence,

$$
\begin{align}
Pr(P_1,P_2,P_3|C_i) & = Pr(P_1|C_i)Pr(P_2|C_i)Pr(P_3|C_i) \\
 & = \frac{Pr(C_i|P_1)P(C_i|P_2)Pr(C_i|P_3)Pr(P_1)Pr(P_2)Pr(P_3)}{[Pr(C_i)]^3}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

on the other hand from Bayes rule we have,

$$
\begin{align}
Pr(C_i|P_1,P_2,P_3) &= \frac{Pr(P_1,P_2,P_3|C_i)Pr(C_i)}{Pr(P_1,P_2,P_3)}\\
&=\frac{Pr(P_1,P_2,P_3|C_i)Pr(C_i)}{Pr(P_1)Pr(P_2)Pr(P_3)}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

From (3) and (4),

$$Pr(C_i|P_1,P_2,P_3) = \alpha Pr(C_i|P_1)P(C_i|P_2)Pr(C_i|P_3)\tag{5}$$

where $\alpha = \frac{1}{[Pr(C_i)]^2}$.

Your approach has two flaws. First, you don't take into account the effect of $\alpha$, and second in general,

$$Pr(C_i|P_1=1,P_2=0,P_3=0)\neq Pr(C_i|P_1=1)$$

In other words,

$$Pr(C_i=1|P_1=1,P_2=0,P_3=0)=0.2, Pr(C_i=1|P_1=0,P_2=1,P_3=0)=0.4 \not\Rightarrow Pr(C_i=1|P_1=1,P_2=1,P_3=0) = 0.2\times 0.4$$

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure that I understand the computation in formula (2). It is the sum of 8 computations of formula (1)?

Comment: @Rob: It is actually sum of eight terms below, $Pr(P_1=\text{T},P_2=\text{T},P_3=\text{T},C_1,C_2,C_3)+\dots+Pr(P_1=\text{F},P_2=\text{F},P_3=\text{F},C_1,C_2,C_3)$

Comment: Yes, and those terms are calculated from the CPT's as shown in (1). Thank you again!

Comment: @Rob: Yes, each term (out of eight) is calculated using formula (1). You're welcome!

Comment: Can the sum in (2) ever be more than 1? Im thinking no as its a probability.

Comment: @Rob: If each row in CPTs sums to 1, then 8-term summation in (2) will not exceed 1.

Comment: Sorry, that is not clear to me...To me its a sum of x products of numbers between 0 and 1. It is not obvious to me that it will not be more than 1. Also, you said my CPT's were wrong. Yes the ones I put in the graph section of my question is incomplete. They are the direct derived tables from the graph. I do complete them to 2^x where x is the number of P variables by the method i showed in my solution proposal. Did you mean that method does not work?

Comment: @Rob: To see why the summation would not exceed 1, notice that 8-terms summation is a subset of your BN joint probability, hence marginalization in formula (2) will not exceed 1. I couldn't get your second point regarding CPT's. If you complete CPT's correctly, and follow the steps, you will find the answer set. Please clarify your question so that I might be able to help you.

Comment: Under "Here is how I try to solve it" I explain how I generate my CPT's. Is that a valid way of doing it? You said they were wrong and I'm not sure if you meant this method is wrong or just that the three example tables underneath the graph is wrong. They are wrong ofcourse because they have not been completed.

Comment: @Rob: Please note that for a Bayesian Network to be identified you need two materials: the topology of the network and the CPT's. Nonetheless, both of them can be estimated (learned) from data. In your problem, it seems that the topology is known but I'm not sure about CPT's. Are you trying to estimate them?

Comment: Yes, the topology is known. It is a complete bipartite graph with two subsets of edges. You can see that some edges are dotted and some are solid in the graph example. The probability of an edge $P(P_i=T|C_j=T)$ is 0.9999 for solid edges and 0.0001 for dotted edges. The graphs are also bigger than this. The sets of P's and C's are typically bigger than 3, but the number of $P=T$ are limited to 3 and the rest are $P=F$. Just wanted to mention that.

Comment: @Rob: The way you are estimating CPT's (as I can see under "Here is how I try to solve it") is not correct. Please see the Edit 1 section in the answer.

Comment: I see. That should help me. Thanks! I am very grateful that you took your time.

Comment: I have a follow up question on this problem. When finding the set ${P_1, P_2, P_3}$ that maximizes the probability of my observation on $C_i$, say ${C_1=T,C_2=F,C_3=F}$. I'm not sure when to insert this observation on $C$. When computing CPT's I make all computations on $C_i=T$. I was thinking to insert my observation in equation (1) by calculating it like $Pr(C_1|P_1,P_2,P_3)\times(1-Pr(C_1|P_1,P_2,P_3))\times(1-Pr(C_1|P_1,P_2,P_3))$. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, the index on the C's are wrong. It should be $Pr(C_1|P_1,P_2,P_3)×(1−Pr(C_2|P_1,P_2,P_3))×(1−Pr(C_3|P_1,P_2,P_3))$.

Comment: @Rob: I'm sorry I didn't get your point. If you have already designed your CPT's correctly (they **must** have 8 rows), then by observing $C_1=T,C_2=F,C_3=F$ you just follow the steps I mentioned in the answer, and you will find the most probable set of $P_i$'s.

Comment: OK you answered my question. Regarding $\alpha$. $\alpha$ is calculated from the probability of $P(C_i=T)$. That implies some previous knowledge of this system that I do not have in this case. Does that mean can use $\alpha = 1$ instead? Or how would I handle that?

Comment: @Rob: I think you don't have enough samples to create CPT's from. You can assume that α=1, and test your assumption against your test set. However, since it seems that there are not enough samples to create CPT's form, and the fact that you are probably trying to solve a "Decoding Problem", I strongly suggest using Hidden Markov models (HMM) approach instead. Have you heard of HMM? It is a very powerful tool to deal with problems like yours in hand.